# How to transfer files from oracle vm

Tags: virtual-machine, file-transfer

Is it possible to copy files from [Oracle VM](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/virtualization/oraclevm/index.html) desktop to the other local windows?

Comment: Can Oracle VM access the local network (or even a fake host-only network), if so just setup a network share and use that. Or, can you configure the VM to mount folders from the host and then use them directly. *(**Note:** I've not used Oracle VM - but you can do both these things in VirtualBox and other VM's so I'd be surprised if you can't here)*

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. You have to go to Settings-->Advanced and set "Drag'nDrop" to Bidirectional. You may also have to install the VM extensions before doing so(Devices-->Install guest additions mounts a cd and then you may have to go run setup if it does not autorun).

Answer (score 2):

Only way i am able to do it personally is to

> Write the files in a CD/DVD disk from
>   the Oracle VM then copy pasting the
>   files to your Desktop from the CD/DVD
>
> Alternatively you can also transfer
>   the files to your desktop via a
>   Pen-drive

According to me the best way to share would be to Share a Folder which then can be shared by the host and guest. But I am not able to share my folder hence cant provide you the steps. Perhaps this section could help you http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#id2654538

Comment: yes, shared folders would be the best way to do this. You need to have Guest Additions installed in the guest for this to work though.